# Incidence Matrix for Finding Neighbor (both left and right) in Circular Blocks (column)

Tags: r

Consider a matrix with `r` rows and `c` columns and containing `v` integers between 0 and `v-1`; in the following example, `r=4`, `c=2`, and `v=6`.

```
L <- c(0,1,1,2,0,1,2,3)
(x <- matrix(L,nrow=4,ncol=2,byrow = TRUE))

 ## 0 1 
 ## 1 2 
 ## 0 1 
 ## 2 3
```

The goal is to generate a `r*c` (row) by `v` column incidence matrix, as follows:

- each row corresponds to one element of the original matrix (in column-major order, i.e. in the example here the 4th row corresponds to `x[4,1]` and the 5th row corresponds to `x[1,2]`)
- find the "neighbors" above and below each element, wrapping around (cyclically) from the top to the bottom of the matrix; count the number of neighbor elements for each value of `v`.

For example, the first element in the matrix (`x[1,1]`) has neighbours `1` (below) and `2` ("above", i.e. wrapped around to the bottom of the column; thus we enter 1 in columns 2 and 3 of row 1, matching the corresponding elements of `0:(v-1)`. The rest of the row is set to zero:

```
  rownames  0  1  2  3  4  5            
  [1]       0  1  1  0  0  0
```

The next element (`x[2,1]`) has `0` on both sides (above and below), so the first column (corresponding to 0) is set to 2, with the rest of the elements equal to zero.

```
  [2]       2  0  0  0  0  0
```

The full matrix for the example above is:

```
  rownames  0  1  2  3  4  5            
  [1]       0  1  1  0  0  0
  [2]       2  0  0  0  0  0
  [3]       0  1  1  0  0  0
  [4]       2  0  0  0  0  0
  [5]       0  0  1  1  0  0
  [6]       0  2  0  0  0  0
  [7]       0  0  1  1  0  0  
  [8]       0  2  0  0  0  0
```

The row sums are each 2.

Comment: Looks like homework assignment! What have you tried? People here won't write code for you? You have to try yourself and then show us what effort have you put in attempting solution

Comment: @geektrader. I have searched and tried but cannot able to find something relevant.

Comment: @user1855677 I mostly saw that you have answered such questions. please help me

Comment: I don't see why this is such a bad question. Somewhat localized of course, and not showing much evidence of research effort (but that should lean to downvotes, not closure) but the techniques needed seem pretty general -- and it seems too odd/obscure to be a homework question (more context wouldn't hurt).  I have a solution, although I don't see why the result would have 12 rather than 8 rows (i.e. it should have number of rows equal to the total number of matrix elements, right?) -- maybe this is left over from a previous version?

Comment: @BenBolker thanks a lot for appreciation and valuable comments. yes you r right that the rows are equal to no of elements (8). can i ask it again for the sake of Answer?

Comment: I have edited accordingly

Comment: @BenBolker I am waiting for solution, Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L =c(0,1,1,2,0,1,2,3)
x=matrix(L,nrow=4,ncol=2,byrow = TRUE)
```

There might be a cleaner way to do this:

```
wrapind <- function(i,n)
    ifelse((r <- i %% n) == 0, n, r)


n <- nrow(x)
v <- 6
incmat <- matrix(0,ncol=v,nrow=prod(dim(x)),
                 dimnames=list(NULL,0:(v-1)))
k <- 1
for (i in seq(ncol(x)))
    for (j in seq(nrow(x))) {
        cat(i,j,k,"\n")  ## unnecessary
        tt <- table(as.character(x[wrapind(c(j-1,j+1),n),i]))
        incmat[k,names(tt)] <- tt
        k <- k+1
    }
```

Comment: Now the problem is that the matrix "x" is comes through a loop. At every iteration the matrix "x" has changed. the above given function for incidence matrix affect generated  matrix. I cannot understand that how the suggested function can changed the rows of a matrix which already exists and being used in the function?

Comment: these are the codes for producing "x"       `k=3
      t=2
         for(i in 1:t){
         v=((2*i)+1)
         h=seq(from=0, to=i, by=1)
         q1=NULL
         q3=NULL
         x=NULL
          for(j in 1:i){
           q1=c((v-(4*h[j]+1)))
           q3=c(((4*h[j])+3))
           T=c(q1,q3)
           y=c(0)
           IB=t(c(y,cumsum(T)%%v))
           l=NULL
            for(i in 1:k)
            for(j in 0:(v-1)){
            l=c(l,rep((IB[i]+j+v)%% v))
            }
  x1= matrix(c(l),nrow=k,ncol=v,byrow = TRUE)
  x=cbind(x,x1)
          }
  }`